# How can I prevent KML files from losing resolution when exporting them to other programs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml, ipad

I have created a KML from a polygon in GIS. The KML is the same in Google Earth as it is in ArcMap. When I load the KML onto my iPad using the app GIS Pro, it loses resolution; it no longer has the level of detail it did. This only happens to some KMLs, others are fine. The one I'm having a problem with now is 2114 KB.

I will try splitting up the KML to see if it's a file size issue. I would like a preventative solution because I have to make and load KMLs iteratively for time-sensitive fieldwork.

Edits: responses to comments incorporated into question. Working on an image

Comment: When you say GIS Pro do you mean ArcGIS Pro or something else?

Comment: What kind of KML is it?  Points? Lines? Polygons? Image overlays?  Something else?  And what do you mean by "loses resolution"? Can you provide screenshots or other examples?